# Why does this jQuery event run twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

When you run this code and click `input2`, it will get the focus and `.result` div will output `"f2"` once. But when you click `input1`, the script will let `input2` get the focus and `.result` div will output `"f2"` twice, why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>blank</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".input1").click(function(){$(".input2").focus();});
    $(".input2").focus(function(){$(".result").html($(".result").html()+"f2, ");});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <input class="input1" value="click me to set the input2's focus" />
        <input class="input2" value="input2" />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [It does not behave that way for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/mwShP/)

Comment: To me, this works correctly : http://jsfiddle.net/FLXfm/

Comment: @Pointy: [or me](http://jsfiddle.net/rbxeN/) (beat me to it :P)

Comment: Oh, it does not work properly in Internet Explorer! got it.

Comment: Which browser? I've tested it on Chrome and it's output just one f2.

Comment: Wow you're right, and it doesn't work in 1.7.1 either. It also doesn't help to put the call to ".focus()" in a timeout handler. Looks like a jQuery bug to me. (Testing in IE7.)

Comment: The `focus` is incorrectly called twice in IE.

Comment: It only happens in ie, everyone.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known jquery bug :

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6705

IE incorrectly calls the `focus` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Fixed... switched to focusin from focus removing the not getting focus in input2 bug.

This appears to be an Internet Explorer only issue. Add a call to preventDefault to fix the double focus issue.  [Here's a jsFiddle of it working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vFQ7p/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>blank</title> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $(".input1").click(function(){$(".input2").focus();}); 
      $(".input2").focusin(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".result").html($(".result").html()+"f2, ");
      }); 
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
    <p> 
      <input class="input1" value="click me to set the input2's focus" /> 
      <input class="input2" value="input2" /> 
      <div class="result"></div> 
    </p> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but it also prevents the .input2 from actually getting focussed. :/

Comment: But when I add the preventDefault, the input2 can't get focus

Comment: Haha, I didn't notice that at all.

Comment: I had the same solution working in jsFiddle aswell, and noticed just before I started posting it here :)

Comment: Add the preventDefault method is equal to add a "return false".

Comment: Fixed... I changed it to the focusin event.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why?

Comment: Well, you can actually just switch focus to focusin and your issue is fixed... but to explain my logic... focus is what causes the mouse to go into the textbox (to actually get the focus). By using focusin the textbox already has the focus.  Preventing default will still stop the default behavior but this time it will be of the focusin event and not the focus event.

Answer (score 0):

Although it appears not to be replicated, I have seen this sort of problem occur when multiple events are bound to the control. This can occur when you end up binding the focus() event twice. It may be worth exploring this, and clearing existing bindings before the code.

Comment: Unneccesary in this case, it's a clear bug in IE as shown by running the jsfiddle examples in IE