# JQuery live doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get .live content into a div when there is a keyup... I looked at the forumtopic here but I didn't find the answer...

Why does my code not works? I use this JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
// When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)

  $(".atleetnaamlink").live('keyup', function(){
    alert('test');
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: $(selector).live(events, data, handler); // jQuery 1.3+  

$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+

$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 3):

try `on`

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("body").on('keyup' ,'.atleetnaamlink', function(){
   alert('test');
 });  
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/4Ksur/3/)**

Comment: Thanks! Now it works with ==> jsfiddle.net/oli4tje/4Ksur/2 But now I want to get a change on change OR keyup. What needs a change? And I want load a content of another page when keyup (or change) from .naam in the div .naamid! Normally I work with .get jquery. Can I do this agian?

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. That will work.

```
$(".atleetnaamlink").on('keyup', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
Now it works with ==> http://jsfiddle.net/oli4tje/4Ksur/2/

But now I want to get a change on change OR keyup. What needs a change?
And I want load a content of another page when keyup (or change) from .naam in the div .naamid! Normally I work with .get jquery. Can I do this agian?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `});` and **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JwRRH/

Hope it helps `:)` by the way `live` is deprecated and if you keen check this out [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926)

**code**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)

      $(".atleetnaamlink").live('keyup', function(){
        alert('test');
      });  
    });​
```

**or***

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        // When the document is ready set up our sortable with it's inherant function(s)

          $(document).live('keyup',".atleetnaamlink", function(){
            alert('test');
          });  
        });​
```

Comment: @OlivierPeeters cool man no probs rest above should help. See the working demo attached http://jsfiddle.net/JwRRH/ `:)`

Comment: Thanks! Now it works with ==> jsfiddle.net/oli4tje/4Ksur/2 But now I want to get a change on change OR keyup. What needs a change? And I want load a content of another page when keyup (or change) from .naam in the div .naamid! Normally I work with .get jquery. Can I do this agian?

Comment: Yes I know but I get 2 message when I type a letter?

Comment: @OlivierPeeters weird I get only one alert, Anyhoo look in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576475/why-does-this-jquery-event-run-twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
```

and see if this works.

and important thing not to forget to accept it if it solves your issue.